# How do I select all values which satisfy certain aggregate properties?

Tags: sql

Say, I have a table (named "Customers") which consists of:

1. CustomerName
2. Country
3. City

I am trying to list the names of all customers from cities where there are at least two customers.

This is my initial attempt:

```
SELECT CustomerName, City
FROM Customers
GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(City) > 1
```

This is the result that I got:

| CustomerName | City |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | New York |
| Person C | Los Angeles |

Here, Person A is a person from NY who appears on the top of the table and similar for Person B. However, what I wanted was the listing of all customers from New York and LA.

When I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerName), City
FROM Customers
GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(City) > 1
```

I had

| COUNT(CustomerName) | City |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | New York |
| 5 | Los Angeles |

This means that the code is working properly, except that my original code only displays a person on top of the table from NY and LA. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please see [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get cities with more than 1 customer in a subquery, and use that list to select the customers:

```
SELECT cst.CustomerName
FROM Customers cst
WHERE Cst.City in (
    -- All cities where there are at least two customers
    SELECT CstGE2.City
    FROM Customers CstGE2
    GROUP BY CstGE2.City
    HAVING count(*) >= 2
)
```

Comment: Just wondering, is it a better practice to aliasing table names? I see that you aliased Customers by Cst and CstGE2

Comment: Without claiming that I chose the best aliases, using meaningful (to the role the table plays in the query) but short aliases is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I've taken the city out of the select part since you said you just wanted customer names.

```
SELECT a.CustomerName
FROM Customers a
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(b.CustomerName)
    FROM Customers b
    WHERE b.City = a.City
) > 1
ORDER BY a.CustomerName
```